# Is there a regex to mask all characters excluding first & last characters in each word

Tags: java, regex, regexp-replace

For example, I have below list of words to be masked.

```
India
Australia
North America
South America
White House building
```

I need an output like below.

```
Ixxxa
Axxxxxxxa
Nxxxh Axxxxxa
Sxxxh Axxxxxa
Wxxxe Hxxxe bxxxxxxg
```

using below expression I'm able to mask last characters including spaces.

```java
return input.replaceAll("[\\s()]+", " ").replaceAll("\\d(?=(?:\\D*\\d){4})","X");
```

Comment: Why are you matching digits? Are there only word character? `\B[a-z](?=[a-z]*[a-z]\b)` https://regex101.com/r/52OVyt/1

Comment: Maybe just `replaceAll("\\B\\w\\B", "x")`? Or `replaceAll("\\B\\p{L}\\B", "x")`?

Comment: If you want to match all non whitespace characters, you can use lookarounds `(?<=\S)\S(?=\S)` https://regex101.com/r/0gSM5x/1 See https://ideone.com/nHEPiA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To match a non whitepace char except for the "outer" ones, you can assert a non whitespace char `\S` to the left and to the right right:

```
(?<=\S)\S(?=\S)
```

In Java

```
(?<=\\S)\S(?=\\S)
```

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/0gSM5x/1) and a [Java demo](https://ideone.com/nHEPiA).

Java example:

```
    String regex = "(?<=\\S)\\S(?=\\S)";
    String string = "India\n"
 + "Australia\n"
 + "North America\n"
 + "South America\n"
 + "White House building\n"
 + "a\n"
 + "ab\n"
 + "abc\n"
 + "tthis123_isatest\n"
 + "!@#$%";

    String result = string.replaceAll(regex, "x");
    System.out.println(result);
```

Output

```
Ixxxa
Axxxxxxxa
Nxxxh Axxxxxa
Sxxxh Axxxxxa
Wxxxe Hxxxe bxxxxxxg
a
ab
axc
txxxxxxxxxxxxxxt
!xxx%
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about a regex, if you want to do it in a OOP way - but perhaps less efficient - you can split by lines and words and programmatically mask each of them:

```
class MaskedText {
    private final String maskedString;
    private final char maskChar;

    public MaskedText(String maskedString) {
        this(maskedString, 'x');
    }

    public MaskedText(String maskedString, char maskChar) {
        this.maskChar = maskChar;
        this.maskedString = Arrays.stream(maskedString.split("\n"))
                .map(this::maskLine)
                .collect(Collectors.joining("\n"));
    }

    private String maskLine(String rawLine) {
        return Arrays.stream(rawLine.split(" "))
                .map(this::maskWord)
                .collect(Collectors.joining(" "));
    }

    private String maskWord(String rawWord) {
        return rawWord.charAt(0)
                + String.valueOf(maskChar).repeat(rawWord.length() - 2)
                + rawWord.charAt(rawWord.length() - 1);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return maskedString;
    }
}
```

And you can use it like this:

```
@Test
void test() {
    String txt = """
            India
            Australia
            North America
            South America
            White House building
            """;
    MaskedText masked = new MaskedText(txt);

    assertThat(masked.toString()).isEqualTo("""
            "Ixxxa
            Axxxxxxxa
            Nxxxh Axxxxxa
            Sxxxh Axxxxxa
            Wxxxe Hxxxe bxxxxxxg"
            """);
}
```

or directly in the logs: `log.info("account: {}", new MaskedText(account))`

Answer (score 1):

Above suggestion posted to use below regex helped resolving the issue.

(?<=\S)\S(?=\S)

I tested it for both characters & numeric with different combinations. This solved my requirement... thanks.